# nock 'no match' event callback arguments

Tags: node.js, eventemitter, nock

When nock emits a ['no match' event](https://github.com/node-nock/nock#global-no-match-event) sometimes it responds with one argument, sometimes with three. Im not sure what they are. The keys for each argument are as follows:

**When the callback is called with one argument:**

qs, headers, path, protocol, method, hostname, port, socketTimeout, agent, clientName, transportName, maxRedirects, proto, host

**When the callback is called with three arguments:**

domain, _events, _maxListeners, output, outputEncodings, writable, _last, chunkedEncoding, shouldKeepAlive, useChunkedEncodingByDefault, sendDate, _headerSent, _header, _hasBody, _trailer, finished, _hangupClose, socket, connection, _headers, _headerNames, _removedHeader, path, write, end, abort, on, once, metrics, timeoutCb, pipe

dnslookup, socketTimeout, retry, markdown-threshold, port, protocol, hostname, basepath, transport, method, instruments, headers, SVC_CHANNEL_STATUS, debug, path, checkServerIdentity, moduleRef, clientId, clientName, qs, agent, transportName, maxRedirects, proto, host, getHeader

'' (empty string)

**This is the code I used to generate the key list:**

```
nock.emitter.on('no match', function() {
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
        if(typeof arguments[i] === 'object')
            console.log("\t",Object.keys(arguments[i]).join(", "));
        else
            console.log("\t'"+arguments[i]+"'");
    }
});
```